# Convert NSString to 4 by 4 float Matrix

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I was wondering if there is a convenience method or something to change a NSString to an array of floats, for example.

I have a string which reads like this:

```
{{-0.528196, -0.567599, -0.631538, 0}, {0.0786662, -0.773265, 0.629184, 0}, {-0.845471, 0.282651, 0.453086, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

Which I got by the method:

```
NSStringFromGLKMatrix4()
```

And i want to do this:

```
float test[4][4] = {{-0.528196, -0.567599, -0.631538, 0}, {0.0786662, -0.773265, 0.629184, 0}, {-0.845471, 0.282651, 0.453086, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};

return GLKMatrix4MakeWithArray(*test);
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda ugly, but it should work:

```
// your string data
NSString* s = @"{{-0.528196, -0.567599, -0.631538, 0}, {0.0786662, -0.773265, 0.629184, 0}, {-0.845471, 0.282651, 0.453086, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}";

// remove uneccessary characters from string.. 
s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

// build an NSArray with string components and convert them to an array of floats
NSArray* array = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
float data[16];
for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
    data[i] = [[array objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
}

GLKMatrix4 matrix = GLKMatrix4MakeWithArray(data);
```

If you're targeting iOS 4.0 or higher, you might also use `NSRegularExpression` to get the numbers out of the string.

Comment: thank you, just a note, i think there is a typo on the "withstring" since i assume you want to delete all of those symbols so it should be "".

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the good ole Ansi C... sscanf ... is long lost and forgotten.

```
sscanf(...,"{{%f,%f,%f,%f}, ...",...);
```

You can check my sscanf code in the [hexString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056757/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-to-hex-values/8433331#8433331) post as an added example.

Comment: Is this used like sscanf(string,"{{%f,%f,%f,%f},{%f,%f,%f,%f},{%f,%f,%f,%f},{%f,%f,%f,%f}}",data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6],data[7],data[8],data[9],data[10],data[11],data[12],data[13],data[14],data[15]);
??

Comment: Yes... that is correct actually. Make sure your variables are passed by pointer and you can check the return variable to see that all elements were parsed... namely 16. You can also add different parameters between the '%' and 'f' specifiers to change the parsing. See the printf man pages for details on the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve values in an array using `componentsSeparatedByString:` method of `NSString` and then use 
`GLKMatrix4MakeWithArray` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSValue, which is the better alternative provided by Apple for conversion between C type structs and Objective-C objects.

**encoding**

```
GLKMatrix4 encMatrix = /* your matrix */;
NSValue *encMatrixValue = [NSValue value:&encMatrix withObjCType:@encode(GLKMatrix4)];
```

**decoding**

```
GLKMatrix4 decMatrix;
[encMatrixValue getValue:&decMatrix];
```

This is much cleaner and stable than converting GLKMatrix to NSString and back to GLKMatrix.