# How to convert NSString to HEX String in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone

I have a NSString with string like "hello".

Now I want to convert the string into another NSString object which shows a hex string. How to do that ?

Comment: [Here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056757/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-to-hex-values)

Comment: Please search Stackoverflow before posting your question.

Comment: ya i did but i could,t get the proper one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm - apart from the obvious which can be found elsewhere - how about something like:

```
    NSString * str = @"Hello World";

    NSString * hexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                         [NSData dataWithBytes:[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                        length:strlen([str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])]];

    for(NSString * toRemove in [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"<", @">", @" ", nil]) 
        hexStr = [hexStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:toRemove withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"%@", hexStr);
```

which should give an output like

```
    48656c6c6f20576f726c64
```

Optimising this is left as an exercise to the reader :) :)

Comment: it's too good for me, will you guide me some place where i can read about this process.

Comment: I was only joking. More seriously - you want to look at the other examples; stack overflow teems with them 'how-to-convert-an-nsstring-to-hex-values' is a fair start). Secondly - you want to read up on snprintf and/or stringWithFormat and specifically look at the '%x' and '%X' formatters. They take a byte and turn it into a hex value. Looping over the string is your next challenge. But you can turn a string into a byte array with the 'str cStringUsingEncoding..' used in above. Do this one by one, adding a hex to a mutable string and you should get a normal solution.

Comment: are you saying this is a bad solution? how is the other answers better, please help