# how to convert string to hex in iPhone Development

Tags: iphone, string, hex

I'm new to iPhone development, I want to convert a string to hex format.

For example `00A400024F01` to `0x00,0xA4,0x00,0x02,0x4F,0x01` I guess I should start by dividing the string and then convert the grouped value. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I can bet you money this has been asked several times on SO, search it up

Comment: @RohanKapur I really have searched for lot but can't find convert like this in iphone.:)maybe I will win your money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u just found answer from this stackoverflow question:-

[How to convert an NSString to hex values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056757/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-to-hex-values/9398930#9398930)

```
+ (NSString *) stringToHex:(NSString *)str
    {   
        NSUInteger len = [str length];
        unichar *chars = malloc(len * sizeof(unichar));
        [str getCharacters:chars];

        NSMutableString *hexString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        {
            // [hexString [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", chars[i]]]; /*previous input*/
            [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", chars[i]]; /*EDITED PER COMMENT BELOW*/
        }
        free(chars);

        return [hexString autorelease];
    }
```

**UPDATE**

You can divide one sting on to two string using below method:-

```
NSString * mystring = @"Hello,How are you";// suppos your string like that
NSArray * array = [mystring componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString * str1 = [array objectAtIndex:0]; //Hello
NSString * str2 = [array objectAtIndex:1]; //How are you
```

and if you want to murge two string in to one string like :-

```
NSString *str1=@"hi Sweet Lady";
NSString *str2=@"How are you";

NSString *mainstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",str1,str2];
```

> Output is ==== hi Sweet Lady How are you

Comment: thanx,why i haven't seen it before.I will lose money,:P.I will search more about the divide part,thanks again.

Comment: i'm new to iphone can you give me some guide about the divide string part?