# how to convert string to hexadecimal formate in objective c in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am new to objective c and cocoa framework and need to convert a string to hexadecimal format.The string is like

```
    NSString* myString=@"Helo hi";
```

String can contain any character.Anybody help please thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplication:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056757/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-to-hex-values/9398930#9398930

Comment: Actually i want hexadecimal in another way. so can you tell me how to convert character to decimal/byte then decimal to binary. and binary to hexadecimal format.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
    NSString* myString=@"Helo hi";
   const char *hexChar = [myString UTF8String];
    NSMutableString *hexValue = [NSMutableString string];
    while ( *hexChar )
        [hexValue appendFormat:@"%02X" , *hexChar++ & 0x00FF];
```