# Hex string to NSString

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, nsstring, hex

I have an hex string coming from server, I have to convert that hex string to NSString. I used some of the methods found in this post [How to convert an NSString to hex values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056757/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-to-hex-values)

I almost got the same text except that Ú appear randomly in some place.
I've change Ú into bold text to be easy to find in the following example.
Can you guys help me what's wrong with the algorithm.

**My algorithm**

```
- (NSString *) stringFromHex:(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableData *stringData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    unsigned char whole_byte;
    char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < [str length] / 2; i++) {
        byte_chars[0] = [str characterAtIndex:i*2];
        byte_chars[1] = [str characterAtIndex:i*2+1];
        whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);
        [stringData appendBytes:&whole_byte length:1];
    }
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

**Hex string from server**

7539686132564968635943666c6348532f564a656261736b526a47585a75734a625a61316c5753475a645575625a5253386f473574347678694c4930695648704c52473170547a4f6b356552da554675394e58672b6943743857524637557748755961634435306936437a7a535a726d6e53664e6e523862433232594a4f593638655464314c6747324763544f56357a736f544c49734e734ada672f77472f6b6b4b48446c644659426d51334d3dda

**Normal string from server which is RSA encoded string**

u9ha2VIhcYCflcHS/VJebaskRjGXZusJbZa1lWSGZdUubZRS8oG5t4vxiLI0iVHpLRG1pTzOk5eR
UFu9NXg+iCt8WRF7UwHuYacD50i6CzzSZrmnSfNnR8bC22YJOY68eTd1LgG2GcTOV5zsoTLIsNsJ
g/wG/kkKHDldFYBmQ3M=

**Normal string converted using my above algorithm**

u9ha2VIhcYCflcHS/VJebaskRjGXZusJbZa1lWSGZdUubZRS8oG5t4vxiLI0iVHpLRG1pTzOk5eR**Ú**UFu9NXg+iCt8WRF7UwHuYacD50i6CzzSZrmnSfNnR8bC22YJOY68eTd1LgG2GcTOV5zsoTLIsNsJ**Ú**g/wG/kkKHDldFYBmQ3M=**Ú**

Answer (score 0):

The server seems to convert DA to a space, probably because `DA` lies outside the ASCII range, which only runs up to `7A` due to it using only 7 bits.

The algorithm converts `DA` to `Ú`, which seems to be ok when using Latin-1 encoding. Using a different encoding from the list [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/String_Encodings), such as `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, might help.

Comment: Using NSUTF8StringEncoding or others return in empty string or the same result as NSASCIIStringEncoding.
So for now I've to use that
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Ú" withString:@""