# How to Convert NSString to Hexadecimal Value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having NSString value as ,

```
NSString *str_Value = @"12345FTY642493AF3556K7880D46676F9";
```

I need the Output in the below format ,

```
Byte byte_Value[]={0x12,0x34,0x5F,0xF9,0x64,0x24,0x93,0xAF,0x35,0x56,0xA7,0x88,0x0D,0x46,0x67,0x6F};
```

How do i convert NSSTring Value to Byte[] ,Any one could please suggest solution for this.

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056757/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-to-hex-values/3057366

Comment: Goto the link below. This will help you. link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056757/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-to-hex-values/3057366

Answer (score 0):

> How do I convert `NSString` value to `Byte[]`. Any one could please suggest solution for this.

It is not exactly clear what you are asking. The above suggests you just want a *value* of type `Byte[]`, which is the same as `Byte *` in C, while you also show a your desired output as a line of (Objective-)C code initialising an array with an array literal.

If the former then you can:

- Use `UTF8String` to obtain a C style string from your `NSString`. This method returns a `char *`.
- The C function `strlen` will tell you have many characters (bytes) this C string contains.
- You can just cast the `char *` value to a `Byte *` value - they are both pointers to bytes.
- That will give you the number of bytes and a `Byte *` pointer to them. You should copy these bytes, the value returned by `UTF8String` does not reference memory owned by the caller and it will be destroyed/reused by the system. You can use functions such as `memcpy` and `malloc` to do this.

If it is the latter, you want a string containing a representation of a C style declaration, then you can:

- Use `UTF8String` to obtain a C style string from your `NSString`. This method returns a `char *`.
- The C function `strlen` will tell you have many characters (bytes) this C string contains.
- Now process the C string a character (`char`) at a time (using a loop), and with each character format it as hex and append the result to an `NSMutableString` in which you are building up the desired string. You can use the method `appendFormat:` to do this, and the format `%02x` will produce a zero-padded 2 digit hex representation of a `char` value.

If you get stuck once you've written some code ask a new question, include the code you've written, and explain the problem you are having. Someone will probably help you.

HTH

Comment: The OP wants neither.  He wants to *parse* a string containing the representation of hex characters into their binary equivalent.  I.e. `@"010203"` becomes `uint8_t b[3] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };`.

Comment: @trojanfoe - the input string given, "12345FTY...", is not hex; though for characters that are valid hex your explanation matches. you are probably right, only the OP knows....

Comment: Yeah it's a typo if you follow the converted hex `TF => F9`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this example code it will help you

```
NSString * str = @"Hello World";

    NSString * hexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                         [NSData dataWithBytes:[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                        length:strlen([str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])]];

    for(NSString * toRemove in [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"<", @">", @" ", nil]) 
        hexStr = [hexStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:toRemove withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"%@", hexStr);
```

which should give an output like

```
48656c6c6f20576f726c64
```

Comment: That isn't what the OP asked for.  Also what is the code doing?  It's creating a string from data created from a string?  Why?

Answer (score -2):

In Swift you can create an extension.

```
extension NSData {

    func toHexString() -> String {

        var hexString: String = ""
        let dataBytes =  UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>(self.bytes)

        for (var i: Int=0; i<self.length; ++i) {
            hexString +=  String(format: "%02X", dataBytes[i])
        }

        return hexString
    }
}
Then you can simply use:

let keyData: NSData = NSData(bytes: [0x00, 0xFF], length: 2)

let hexString = keyData.toHexString()
println("\(hexString)") // Outputs 00FF
```